# How to add a new nullable String column in a DataFrame using Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

There are probably at least 10 question very similar to this, but I still have not found a clear answer.

How can I add a nullable string column to a DataFrame using scala? I was able to add a column with null values, but the DataType shows null

```
val testDF = myDF.withColumn("newcolumn", when(col("UID") =!= "not", null).otherwise(null))
```

However, the schema shows

```
root
 |-- UID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- IsPartnerInd: string (nullable = true)
 |-- newcolumn: null (nullable = true)
```

I want the new column to be string **|-- newcolumn: string (nullable = true)**

Please don't mark as duplicate, unless it's really the same question and in scala.

Comment: Try `myDF.withColumn("newcolumn", lit(null).cast("string"))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just explicitly cast null literal to `StringType`.

```
scala> val testDF = myDF.withColumn("newcolumn", when(col("UID") =!= "not", lit(null).cast(StringType)).otherwise(lit(null).cast(StringType)))

scala> testDF.printSchema

root
 |-- UID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- newcolumn: string (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want a column which is always null? There are several ways, I would prefer the solution with `typedLit`:

```
myDF.withColumn("newcolumn", typedLit[String](null))
```

or for older Spark versions:

```
myDF.withColumn("newcolumn",lit(null).cast(StringType))
```